# Tag Suggestion: Fault-Tolerance

Tags: discussion

Don't we need a tag about Fault-Tolerance? It is a very important characteristic for applications in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a question (or can find an existing question) about the topic then you are more than welcome to add the tag. Tags cannot exist if there are no questions having that tag - this means we can't create any tags before questions are asked, but can only apply what we think are the relevant tags to existing questions.

You do need 300 rep to be able to create tags - see the [privileges page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), so in the meantime if you do have a question in mind you can do the following:

1. Post a comment on the question suggesting the tag is added.
2. Post a request in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) for someone to add the tag.
3. Post a question here - with a link to the question(s) - suggesting the at the tag is added.